# Can I write a template function for vector and map at the same time?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

Is there a way to write a template function for STL container iterators which works for `std::vector` and `std::map`? The following function works for `std::vector<T>, std::array<T>, std::list<T>`

```
template<class Iterator>
void fun(Iterator f, Iterator l)
{
    for(; f != l; ++f)
    {
        doWork(*f); // or maybe f->doSomething();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the map iterator points on a pair of key and value. Can I overload the function somehow to accept a `map<whatever,T>`?

Comment: The problem is with `doWork`. Not `fun`.
If you can distinguish cases such as `std::map<K, V>` from `std::vector<std::pair<K const, V> >`, then it's relatively simple, depending on the definition of `doWork`.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to doWork on all values. If so I would write *getValue* function, specialize it for pair and make it a forward for all other types. Then use it in *fun*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

template <class T, class U> U & getValue(std::pair<T,U> & p) { return p.second; }
template <class T> T && getValue(T && t) { return std::forward<T>(t); }

void doWork(int) {}

template<class Iterator>
void fun(Iterator f, Iterator l)
{
  for(; f != l; ++f)
    {
      doWork(getValue(*f));
    }
}

int main()
{
  std::map<int, int> m;
  std::vector<int> v;
  fun(m.begin(), m.end());
  fun(v.begin(), v.end());
}
```

Comment: `std::move` in `getValue(T &&)` doesn't look right. Should probably be `std::forward`, with the return type changed to `T &&`. But in any case, it's inconsistent with the first funciton that only works on lvalues.

Comment: sure, fixed, I was thinking about *forward*, wrote *move*, In case of pair function to have best solution I think more than one specializatin for pair is needed. I wrote one for simplicity. But maybe there is a way to write it in one line?

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++17, you can use if constexpr to determine if you dealing with a pair or a value.

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template<class T>
void doWork(T t) {
    t *=2;
}

template <typename T>
struct is_pair : std::false_type { };

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_pair<std::pair<T, U>> : std::true_type { };

template<class Iterator>
void fun(Iterator f, Iterator l)
{
    for(; f != l; ++f)
    {
        if constexpr(is_pair<std::decay_t<decltype(*f)>>::value) {
            doWork(f->second);
        } else {
            doWork(*f);
        }

    }
}
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    std::map<int,int> m;

    fun(v.begin(), v.end());
    fun(m.begin(), m.end());
}
```

Comment: I'd use `std::decay_t` (`std::remove_cvref_t` in C++20) instead of `std::remove_reference_t`, in case the pairs end up being `const`. Or modify `is_pair`.